# Seeking the name of this formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking for a formula that will be used 5 times to give me a desire output of G.

What is a simplified formula that can help me achieve the results below?

$$(Z×A)/B = C,\\
(C×A)/B = D,\\
(D×A)/B = E,\\
(E×A)/B = F,\\
(F×A)/B = G$$

$$Z = 100\\
G = 202.4642195365$$

$$A = .33, B = .38$$

Example above for reference. In this case, A and B had already been solved. My question is, how would I be able to solve had I only known the values of Z and G?

Comment: "Cross product"?  And what do the numerical values of A, B, G, and Z have to do with your question?

Comment: Does "$\times$" mean simple multiplication here?

Comment: This looks like a sequence of equal proportions $a / b = c / z = d / c = e / d = f / e = g / f$. Don't see what it has to do with `linear-algebra` or `cauchy-integral-formula`.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t solve for $A,B,$ but you can solve for $r=A/B.$ Namely, $G=Zr^5,$ so $$r=A/B =\sqrt[5]{G/Z}$$

I don’t think this solution has a name, but the sequence, $Z,C,D,E,F,G$ is called a geometric sequence.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Compound Interest Formula for your savings account in a bank
Given A, B. Define its ratio r' = B/A as follows:
r = (B/A - 1)*100 = 15.15 %     annual interest in percent
G = A* (1 + r) ^5 is the principal plus interest @ r% compounded yearly for 5 years
= 100* (1.1515) ^5
= 202.46

and C,D,E,F are principal plus accumulated interest for the first 4 years respectively.

Check your number using "72 divided by r" rule: Divide 72 by the interest in percent you get yields the amount of time in years it takes for you to double your money!  72/15= 4.8 ~ 5